# HTML5 fb-Comments can not get rid of moderation

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-comments

We are currently using HTML5 to implement facebook comments on our website.  All of our comments are going to the moderation queue even though our settings say "Make every post public by default."

This is the code we have:

```
<div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset"><script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px; "></div></div>

<div class="fb-comments  fb_iframe_widget" data-href="https://anza.mybasis.com/post/4eca892cb618221d6b004d67" data-num-posts="2" data-width="716" parsed-by-basis-view="true"><span>
```

Our facebook settings can be seen here 
  [image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/grow_power/6380198675/]

Anyone have any ideas?